# Playa Children Entries not Displaying When Parent has Same Title as Another Entry

Tags: playa, structure, transcribe

I have a sidebar on my website that is displaying entries using Playa, the client can create new entries for the sidebar, choose what sidebar entries they want to appear and order them however they like. This works but on pages/entries that have the same title the sidebar entries do not appear. Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Sidebar Code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="page" url_title="{embed:parent}"}        
        {sidebar var_prefix="side" transcribe="disable"}

            {side:if channel_short_name == "sidebar_image_component"}
            <div class="component">
                <h4><span class="headerIcon">{side:image_component_header_icon_code}</span>{side:title}</h4>
                <div class="arrowDown"></div>

                <img data-interchange="[{side:image_component_image:small}, (small)], [{side:image_component_image:medium}, (medium)], [{side:image_component_image:large}, (large)]" alt="{side:title}">
                <noscript><img src="{side:image_component_image:large}"></noscript>

                <div class="inner">
                    <p>{side:image_component_text}</p>
                    <a href="{side:image_component_page_link}" class="siteButtonBlue">{side:image_component_link_text} <span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right linkIcon"></i></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/side:if}

            {side:if channel_short_name == "sidebar_text_component"}
            <div class="component textComponent">
                <h4><span class="headerIcon">{side:text_component_header_icon_code}</span>{side:title}</h4>
                <div class="arrowDown"></div>
                <div class="inner">
                    <p>{side:text_component_text}</p>
                    <a href="{side:text_component_page_link}" class="siteButtonBlue">{side:text_component_link_text} <span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right linkIcon"></i></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/side:if}

            {side:if channel_short_name == "mind_map"}
            <div class="component">
                <div class="mindMap {side:mind_map_colour}">
                    <h5>{side:title}</h5>
                    <a href="{side:mind_map_page_link}" class="siteButtonWhite">More Info<span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right linkIcon"></i></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/side:if}

        {/sidebar}        
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's ok, I was passing the url title in as a parameter, I've changed that to be the full url and it is working perfectly.

Thanks.
Stephen.